# Read Binary Data over TCP with Boost::Asio

Tags: c++, boost, stream, boost-asio, binarystream

My program receives binary data over a TCP-Connection. The connection is established using the `boost::asio` library. After reading the stream I need to return the received data as `char*`-Array. This is what I've got so far:

```
char* read()
    {
        boost::system::error_code ec;

        boost::asio::streambuf response;
        size_t bytes = boost::asio::read(this->socket_, response, ec);

        if(ec.value() != boost::system::errc::success)
        {
            cout << "In " << BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION << ": " << ec.category().name() << ':' << ec.value() << endl;
            return "";
        }

        std::istream stream(&response);

        char* ret = new char[bytes]{0};
        int i = 0;
        while(!stream.eof())
        {
            // ..??.. Write into char array
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I'm looking for a function to write the received binary-data into the char-array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) for example.

```
stream.read(ret, bytes);
```

or you can use [sgetn](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sgetn)

```
response.read(ret, bytes);
```

or you can use any other thing.